# SSH tunnelling failure between Metabase and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ssh-tunnel, metabase

Trying to add a Postgres database on Metabase via SSH tunneling I ran into an error giving me the following error message: "Server error encountered"
My logs are very similar to @williamjacksn 's logs on the post:

[http://discourse.metabase.com/t/ssh-tunnel-failure/2469](http://%20http://discourse.metabase.com/t/ssh-tunnel-failure/2469)

I am certain that my credentials are OK since I use the same for a Postico SSH connection as well as a DBeaver connection.

I already checked the following fix: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/6970
Howerver I have no idea how to use it as i cannot find the ssh.clj file on my machine.

Would there be a fix for this ?

Extra info:
Install via the .jar file. Working on Firefox 58.0.2 | Mac OSX 10.10.5

Thanks in advance

Log:

```
03-12 10:16:48 INFO util.ssh :: creating ssh tunnel metabase@192.168.1.2:22 -L 56334:localhost:5432
03-12 10:16:53 ERROR metabase.driver :: Failed to connect to database: Timed out after 5000 milliseconds.
03-12 10:16:53 DEBUG metabase.middleware :: POST /api/setup/validate 400 (5 s) (0 DB calls)
{:errors {:dbname "Timed out after 5000 milliseconds."}}

Mar 12, 2018 10:16:53 AM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:194)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:364)
at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invoke(jdbc.clj:226)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1014)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:996)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1090)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1047)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1063)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1047)
at metabase.driver.generic_sql$can_connect_QMARK_.invokeStatic(generic_sql.clj:220)
at metabase.driver.generic_sql$can_connect_QMARK_.invoke(generic_sql.clj:217)
at metabase.driver$fn__25577$G__25354__25584.invoke(driver.clj:51)
at metabase.driver$can_connect_with_details_QMARK_$fn__25710.invoke(driver.clj:451)
at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4676.invoke(core.clj:1938)
at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:68)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
... 24 more

Mar 12, 2018 10:16:58 AM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:194)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:364)
at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invoke(jdbc.clj:226)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1014)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:996)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1090)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1047)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1063)
at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1047)
at metabase.driver.generic_sql$can_connect_QMARK_.invokeStatic(generic_sql.clj:220)
at metabase.driver.generic_sql$can_connect_QMARK_.invoke(generic_sql.clj:217)
at metabase.driver$fn__25577$G__25354__25584.invoke(driver.clj:51)
at metabase.driver$can_connect_with_details_QMARK_$fn__25710.invoke(driver.clj:451)
at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4676.invoke(core.clj:1938)
at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:68)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
... 24 more`
```

Answer (score 0):

> I already checked the following fix: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/6970 Howerver I have no idea how to use it as i cannot find the ssh.clj file on my machine.

To try out the `ssh.clj` changes proposed in the pull request you need to get the source code from GitHub, then build Metabase yourself from source code. I just happen to have described the steps over on the Metabase discussion forum for someone in a similar situation (though needing a different PR for a different purpose):

http://discourse.metabase.com/t/snowflake-driver-test/3110